# Get the Azure Directory Name by PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, az

How can I get the Azure Directory(Tenant) name in which I have logged in by PowerShell ?

I have tried 'Get-AzContext', but it only provides the Tenant ID. Tenant name or default domain name is not included in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Get-AzTenant`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/get-aztenant?view=azps-4.5.0) will help.

```
Get-AzTenant
   [[-TenantId] <String>]
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

[image]

---

Make sure the version of Az is 4.5.0(the latest version).
You could `Install-Module -Name Az` to update it.

[image]

Comment: Nope, It only provides the ID of the Tenants, I can't find any tenant name  in the output.

Comment: @SouravKarmakar Is the version of Az 4.5.0?

Comment: Thanks @PamelaPeng, I was using an older version(3.5.0) of Az module.

Comment: @PamelaPeng Great solution, I tried the above to and failed since I hadnt updated my Az module. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the command [`Get-AzureADTenantDetail`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadtenantdetail?view=azureadps-2.0)

```
Get-AzureADTenantDetail
   [-All <Boolean>]
   [-Top <Int32>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan.  The above script belongs to AzureRm module, I 'm currently using Az module and can't use AzureRm along with it.

Comment: @SouravKarmakar You are incorrect, it belongs to the AzureAD module as I showed in my answer above. AzureAD and Az can be used together. :)

Comment: Yes @DanielBjörk I was wrong. But, I have got the simpler way to get the work done. Get-AzTenant with the updated Az module has solved my problem.

Comment: @SouravKarmakar yeah I saw that too, I upvoted that solution since and commented it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need the AzureAD module for PowerShell and you will get the information by Connecting and then running the Get-AzureADTenantDetail

```
Install-Module AzureAD
Connect-AzureAD
Get-AzureADTenantDetail
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the tenant name for the tenant that you have logged in using the Powershell Az module:

```
$azTenantId = (Get-AzContext).Tenant.Id
$azTenantName = (Get-AzTenant | where-object Id -eq $azTenantId).Name
```

To get the default tenant domain for the tenant that you have logged in:

```
$azTenantDomain = Invoke-AzRestMethod `
                    -Method get `
                    -Uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/domains `
                        | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content `
                        | Convertfrom-json `
                        | Select-Object -ExpandProperty value `
                        | where-object -Property  isDefault -eq $true `
                        | Select-Object -ExpandProperty id
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into this - the problem may also be (and was for me) if you're signed in with a service principal with certificate it doesn't have the tenant information in Get-AzTenant (because the REST API itself doesn't provide the information to service principals).

Like mpowrie said you need to switch to Graph API.